# Mule integration with JIRA

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule-connector

I have an use case to fetch number of issues created and fixed by each user in Jira on a daily basis. The plan is to fetch this once a day and not in real-time. We may also need to do some processing on data retrieved from Jira and then store the data in Microsoft SQL Server. The peak number of records for issues created/ fixed can be assumed to be in range of 10K/ day.

AFAIK, there is no Mule Jira connector capability that allows this. However, questions are:

1. Is there any Jira API that allows us to achieve the use case?
2. Is this capability supported by Mule Jira connector?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can create that query in JIRA, then JIRA provides a [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/) that will allow you to execute it. You could call the API using the Mule HTTP connector to make the requests, process them and insert into SQL Server through the Mule Database connector.

There is a [JIRA REST API connector for Mule 4](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.hotovo/mule-jira-connector/) that uses above mentioned JIRA REST API. It might simplify the usage but you will have to investigate it to see if it matches your needs. Check the documentation link for licensing information.